# Create trigger sytax error in sybase

Tags: triggers, sybase

Below is the code i am using to create a trigger(before insert):

```
ALTER TRIGGER "delete_entry_before_inserting" BEFORE INSERT
ORDER 1 ON "XYZ"."ABC"
REFERENCING NEW AS "inserted" 
FOR EACH ROW /* WHEN( search_condition ) */
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (select hostname from ABC WHERE hostname = inserted.hostname) THEN
        UPDATE ABC
        SET days_count = (days_count + 1)
        WHERE hostname = inserted.hostname
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END IF
END
```

But the above thing is giving me error as: syntax error near rollback transaction on line 11

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` somewhere in your code.

Check [this](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.commands/html/commands/commands81.htm) documentation.

Comment: Not working after removing semi colon.
Now the error says: syntax error near rollback on line 11